# Shift heading levels

Tags: wikipedia

When editing Wikipedia, I want to turn several sections into subsections in order to group them into one section. So within them, I have to turn section headings into subsection headings, but also subsection headings into sub-sub-section headings, and so on.

Is there a one-click solution, or do I have to write a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an existing default tool or [user script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:User_scripts/List) for this. You'd either need to code it yourself or do it in regex.